# blank space left even after setting match_parent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

i have created an Toolbar with navigation drawer and menu, now i'm trying to add a textView and edittext on the same toolbar and place them in the center, but the problem is when i add relative layout and set width as match parent, it leases some space on the left side and the items which are to be placed in the center are shifted right.

i've pasted the code below:-

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="130dp"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="H E A D"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/ToolbarTextView"
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorwhite"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ToolbarTextView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Tagline"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorwhite"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="292dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/main_search"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorwhite"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:hint="Search..."
            android:id="@+id/ToolbarSearch1"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar></android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout><include layout="@layout/content_main" /><android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
android:id="@+id/fab"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

the xml code of the mainActivity:-

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.strease.user.strease.MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/layout4"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/></android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

the reference image is given below:-

[image: Reference image]

Screenshot of the device is given below:-

[image: screenshot]

P.S:- i need to omit the blank space and get the editText and textViews to the center of the layout(currently the are shifted towards right)

Navigation Drawer code in main Activity:-

```
  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start"><include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/></android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this *properties* to *Toolbar* to remove that space.

```
android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
```

*Like* as below.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
```

This will remove the default left space from *Toolbar*.

Here is screen shot. It seems *Edit Text* showing in exact *center* of *Toolbar*. Also update your *minSdkVersion* to *21* surely it will work.

Here is the *layout* code.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/colorAccent"
        android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ToolbarTextView"
                style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
                android:text="H E A D"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ToolbarTextView"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Tagline"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/ToolbarSearch1"
                android:layout_width="292dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
                android:hint="Search..."
                android:padding="7dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

**EDIT**

Add another property to *toolbar* for *Navigation Icon*.

```
app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
```

Now your *toolbar* should be as below.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/colorAccent"
        android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp">
```

**EDIT 2**

I have made some changes to your *layout* used *Linear Layout* instead of *Relative Layout*.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/colorAccent"
        android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ToolbarTextView"
                style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="H E A D"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tagline"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/ToolbarSearch1"
                android:layout_width="292dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
                android:hint="Search..."
                android:padding="7dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried...but it is not completely solving my problem....it has omitted the blank space however if you look in the image i have an editText and i have passed layout_centerHorinzontal="true"
But still the editText is a bit towards right and is not completely in center

Comment: @jpsingh It is showing in center with your code and after added that properties it seems to work as intended please double check !!. I am sharing SS check updated answer.

Comment: I know sir, even in Android studio it is showing in the center but when run on a device or emulator it is shifted a bit towards right...
I'm not sure why is this happening
But is it due to the 3 lines logo of navigation drawer?

Comment: @jpsingh That screen shot is of real device !! you can see updated answer. Also make sure your *minSdkVersion* should be *21* because those properties won't work below that.

Comment: @jpsingh Did that worked now as per above suggestion and comments ?

Comment: I have edited the question and have pasted the screenshot, please refer to the image, you will clearly see there is more space on the left of the editText than on right.

Comment: @jpsingh Just add this property in your *toolbar* portion *app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"* and there you go. Also check my edited answer. Hopefully it will work now.

Comment: Still the same....nothing has changed even after adding those lines....on Android studio....it is showing completely in the center however in device it is still the same

Comment: Yes i have changed that as well but it didn't made any difference

Comment: @jpsingh Can you show me your *drawer layout* code as well ?

Comment: @jpsingh Can you try my updated answer with *EDIT 2* part. I have made some change to your *layout*. Inside *Toolbar* used *Linear Layout* instead of *Relative Layout*. Can u check and let me know if that works!

Answer (score 0):

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
```

Comment: I have done that however still the editText (which is shown in image) is not in the center of the layout, it is still shifted towards right

Answer (score 0):

```
app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"  
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"  
app:contentInsetRight="0dp"  
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
```

Try to add above four line in your toolbar. It will resolve your problem. And make your child layout inside width match_parent and height wrap_content. And set your sub child view alignment center to horizontally. It will resolve your problem.

If still not resolve your problem then update your XML file for your layout exactly with the included layout so we can find out what exactly problem going on with your layout.

Comment: I've already done all that still the issue is same.
In Android studio....it show everything to be aligned in center however when i run it on a real device. The editText is still inclined towards right.

Comment: I've also added app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
Still nothing has changed

Comment: Have you check it with layout bounds in device what exactly going wrong with your view. If possible try to upload a screenshot of your device with layout bound view. And update your XML more properly so we can check it correctly.